# Moving DIV across the screen

Tags: javascript, html

```
var move = function() {

  var figur_1 = document.getElementById('figur_1');

  figur_1.style.top++;

  window.requestAnimationFrame(move);

}

move();
```

I want to move a div with id **figur_1** over the screen.

How can this be done?

```
var move = function() {

  var figur_1 = document.getElementById('figur_1');


  figur_1.style.position = 'absolute';
  figur_1.style.top += '1px';


  window.requestAnimationFrame(move);

}

move();
```

does no animation, too. It just moves the DIV 1px down!

Comment: Can the solution be jQuery?

Comment: no, i want to use pure javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make a div move across the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699330/make-a-div-move-across-the-screen)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this functionality by a single function. You need to work with at least two function. One is `mousedown` event and another is `mouseup` event. Because, you dont want anymore dragging action after user releases the mouse key.

HTML:

```
<div id="figur_1">
    This div is movable. Lets try dragging.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#figur_1{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #0000ff;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    color: yellow;
    cursor: move;
}
```

JS:

```
figur_1.onmousedown = function (e) {
    var figur_1 = document.getElementById("figur_1");

    var left = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle(figur_1).getPropertyValue("left") );
    var top = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle(figur_1).getPropertyValue("top") );
    var mouseX = e.clientX;
    var mouseY = e.clientY;

    document.onmousemove = function (e) {
        var dx = mouseX - e.clientX;
        var dy = mouseY - e.clientY;

        figur_1.style.left = left - dx + "px";
        figur_1.style.top = top - dy + "px";
    };
};

figur_1.onmouseup = function () {
    document.onmousemove = null;
};
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sajibche/4xfuemrb/

Comment: sorry but i didn't want to drag n drop the div. i wanted it to simply move across the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a mode easy and short for move an element with a few code.

```
var move = function() {

  var figur_1 = document.getElementById('figur_1');

  figur_1.style.position = "absolute";
  figur_1.style.top = "100px";
}

move();
```

```js
var move = function() {

  var figur_1 = document.getElementById('figur_1');

  figur_1.style.position = "absolute";
  figur_1.style.top = "100px";
}

move();
```

```html
<div id="figur_1">TEST</div>
```

t
You can use also `.style.bottom/top/left/right`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this drag and drop?

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop