# Moving <span> elements left and right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move  elements on the x-axis

I'm trying to add a slideshow to my webpage. I've added Dots to show which picture the slideshow is currently on.

I've managed to make use of 'Float' to move the dots up and down, but they won't co-operate with left and right.

If you need more info, let me know

```css
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 230px 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make a div move across the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699330/make-a-div-move-across-the-screen)

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this and how you want the dots to move is not clearly stated in the question.

For example, you may want to utilize `display:flex` and there are several features you can utilize from it, like maybe programmatically moving a style attribute `margin-right: auto` between the `.dot` divs or something else.

You may also do it with `psoition: absolute`, provided that you have a fixed value for the width and height of the dots, and that the parent element/container can be `position: relative`, alignment will not be that hard.

With what you currently have, maybe playing with their `padding` or `margin` on their left or right is enough to make the dots "move".

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this.

```
<style>
.dot-wrapper {
    height:200px; 
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:4px;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}  
</style>

<div class="dot-wrapper">
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></div>
  <div class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></div>
</div>
```